# TypError 4 instead of expected 3 arguments in super().__init_ call

Tags: python, init, super

#### Error Message

I got this message

```
File ...
    super().__init__(self, self.event_pattern, stm)
TypeError: RegExpTokenizer.__init__() takes 3 positional arguments but 4 were given
```

### The Code

```
class BaseClassName():

    def __init__(self, event_pattern, stm):
        self.__eventPattern = event_pattern
        self.__stm = stm


class SomeClassName(BaseClassName):
    event_pattern = {
        'name1': "value1",
        'name2': "value2",
        'name3': "value3",
        'name4': "value4",
        'name5': "value5"
    }

    def __init__(self, stm):
        super().__init__(self, self.event_pattern, stm)
```

#### Question

The call to `super().__init__` takes only the 3 expected arguments,
where is the complained 4 argument? I can't see it.

I tried to compile the code.

Is it impossible to reference the class `variable(event_pattern)` in `__init__` method?

Comment: You're not supposed to pass `self` to a method you call with `super`. `super` handles that.

Comment: Where is the code for the base class. My guess, you don't have to pass `self`

Comment: @user2357112 PyCharm generates the super call with self as first parameter.
 I assume that should be correct.

Comment: @buran as you can see the super init method takes 3 arguments as it is claimed in the error message. The message suggests the 4. argument must be introduced by the inti-call in the subclass but there are only 3 arguments in the list.

Comment: `super().__init__` produces a *bound* method, which is essentially a wrapper around  `self` and the function `__init__`. Calling the bound method calls the function with `self` and the method's own arguments. If *you* pass `self` explicitly as an argument, it gets passed to the function twice.

Comment: @chepner Thanks for the info. I remove the self argument from the list and and it worked

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to omit the `self` argument in the `super().__init__` call:

```
def __init__(self, stm):
        super().__init__(self.event_pattern, stm)
```

The hint came from chepner see his comment.